# Making points appear on top of lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, overlapping-features, mapping

[image]

Lines are showing on top of points when I want them to show behind. Please see picture for reference.

Comment: You can drag the point layer above the line layer in the Layers pane.

Comment: @Matt this look to be an answer rather than a comment. Perhaps you could make it one.

Answer (score 4):

###### Simple solution

You can drag the point layer above the line layer in the Layers pane.

[image]

###### More advanced solution

Enable the *Layer Order* panel via `View > Panels > Layer Order`

[image]

In the Layer Order Panel:

1. Check the *Control rendering order* option.
2. Order your layers as desired.

This method allows you to have a specific layer hierarchy in your project but still have a lot of control over how your map is rendered. Notice that the layers do not change order in the Layers panel, but the point now appears on top of the line.

[image]